# Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object

Tags: php, pdo

Good day everyone. I am trying to run my query but everytime I try to run it, it would give me this kind of error:  Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object. I don't really grab the whole idea on what is this problem all about and how it is caused.

Here is my code.

**bookReserve.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include_once "../styles/header-menu-out.php";
    include_once "dbconnection.php";


    function __autoload($class){
        include_once("../main/".$class.".php");}

        $code = new codex_books();

        $sname = $_POST['sname'];
        $sid = $_POST['sid'];
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $author = $_POST['author'];
        $isbn = $_POST['isbn'];
        $publisher = $_POST['publisher'];
        $language = $_POST['language'];
        $genre = $_POST['genre'];
        $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
        $date_to_be_borrow = $_POST['date_to_be_borrow'];
        $statement = $code->bookreserve1($id,"book_info");

        if(isset($_POST['reserve']))
        {
            while($row = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            {
                $oldstock=$row['quantity'];
            }

            $newstock = $oldstock-$quantity;
            $code->bookreserve2($newstock,"book_info");
            $code->bookreserve3($q,"reserve_list");
        }
        else
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
                    alert('Successfully Reserved.');
                    window.location='bookReservelist.php';
                </script>";

?>
```

**codex_books.php**

```
public function bookreserve1($id, $table)
{
    $q = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE id = :id";
    $stmt = $this->con->prepare($q);
    $stmt->execute(array(':id'=>$id));
    $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $result;
}
```

Can you help me solve this problem and make me understand this error in layman's term? I am new to this. Hope you can understand. Thanks

Comment: $code->bookreserve1($id,"book_info") is returning false. So the problem lies somewhere in bookreserve1 method.

Comment: `var_dump($statement);`.

Comment: @web2students.com my mistake, I have posted the wrong lines of codes. Edited it already.

Comment: And If you're using fetchAll then you should use foreach($statement->fetchAll() as $row) or just while($row = $statement->fetch())

Comment: For your code to work you should return the $stmt object from bookreserve1. Or the array returned by $stmt->fetchAll(). Then later iterate over it using foreach($arr_book_info as $row)

Comment: At one place you are calling `$row = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` it gives all rows so no need to use while loop.

Comment: @Ivarpoiss Can you give me some tips on how to return $stmt objects from bookreserve1?

Comment: `$q = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE id > :id"; 
$stmt = $this->con->prepare($q); 
$stmt->execute(array(':id',0)); 
$rows = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); print_r($rows);`
Run above code and see output, you will understand it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
public function bookreserve1($id, $table)
{
    $q = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE id = :id";
    $stmt = $this->con->prepare($q);
    $stmt->execute(array(':id'=>$id));
    //fetchAll gets all rows found by query, as an array of rows.
    //In your code $result = $stmt->fetch() returned only the first row, as ann associative array.
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $result;
}
```

and

```
function __autoload($class) {include_once("../main/".$class.".php");}

$code = new codex_books();

$sname = $_POST['sname'];
$sid = $_POST['sid'];
$id = $_POST['id'];
$title = $_POST['title'];
$author = $_POST['author'];
$isbn = $_POST['isbn'];
$publisher = $_POST['publisher'];
$language = $_POST['language'];
$genre = $_POST['genre'];
$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
$date_to_be_borrow = $_POST['date_to_be_borrow'];

$result = $code->bookreserve1($id,"book_info");

if(isset($_POST['reserve']))
{
    //Iterate over the array of rows.
    foreach($result as $row)
    {
        $oldstock=$row['quantity'];
    }

    $newstock = $oldstock-$quantity;

    $code->bookreserve2($newstock,"book_info");
    $code->bookreserve3($q,"reserve_list");
}
else {
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Successfully Reserved.');window.location='bookReservelist.php';</script>";
}
?>
```

In your code the `$statement` variable assigned with `$code->bookreserve1` was the first row returned by `$stmt->fetch` which is an array type not a PDO statement object. 
That's why calling `$statement->fetchAll()` resulted in error. $statement was an array at that point.

Comment: Excellent! From what I have noticed from my code to yours, Is it a neccessity to have the same name from your oop code to your pdo code? like that $result?

Comment: From what you have edited, now I understand. Thanks sir

Comment: The variable name "result" is irrelevant. I just changed the name to something other than $statement since it's not a pdo statement, it's an array. $result in bookreserve1 method is entirely different variable in different scope. Just happens to have the same name (and value). Go look up what variable scopes are and how they work. You'll get used to it.